# Derived type in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, derived-types

Is it possible to create a "derived type" from a type? Like `extends` in Java.

For instance I need these types:

```
create type mytype as (
    f1 int,
    --many other fields...
    fn varchar(10)
);

create type mytype_extended as (
    f1 int,
    --many other fields...
    fn varchar(10),

    fx int --one field more
);
```

You can see that this is redundant. If in the future I'll change `mytype`, I'll need to change `mytype_extended` too.

I tried this:

```
create type mytype as (
    f1 int,
    --many other fields...
    fn varchar(10)
);

create type mytype_extended as (
    mt mytype,

    fx int --one field more
);
```

but this leads `mytype_extended` to have just 2 fields, `mt` (a complex type, I think) and `fx`, instead of `f1, f2... fn, fx`.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, there is no direct type inheritance, but you have a few options:

[**1. Table inheritance**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html)

You can create inherited tables to create inherited types (PostgreSQL will always create a composite type for every table, with the same name):

```
create table supertable (
  foo   int,
  bar   text
);

create table subtable (
  baz   int
) inherits (supertable);
```

[**2. Construct views using each other**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html)

Because views are (in reality) tables (with [rules](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules.html)), a type is created for each of them too:

```
create view superview
  as select null::int  foo,
            null::text bar;

create view subview
  as select superview.*,
            null::int  baz
     from   superview;
```

[**3. Type composition**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)

This is what, you've tried. You have more control with this one in general:

```
create type supertype as (
  foo   int,
  bar   text
);

create type subtype as (
  super supertype,
  baz   int
);

-- resolve composition manually
select get_foo(v),        -- this will call get_foo(subtype)
       get_foo((v).super) -- this will call get_foo(supertype)
from   (values (((1, '2'), 3)::subtype)) v(v);
```

**+1 True type inheritance?**

[PostgreSQL's documentation explicitly says](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html), that table inheritance is not the standard's type inheritance:

> SQL:1999 and later define a type inheritance feature, which differs in many respects from the features described here.

Nevertheless, inherited table's auto-created types really work like true inherited types (they can be used, where the super type can be used):

```
-- if there is a get_foo(supertable) function,
-- but there is no get_foo(subtable) function:

select get_foo((1, '2')::supertable);  -- will call get_foo(supertable)
select get_foo((1, '2', 3)::subtable); -- will also call get_foo(supertable)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5c569/2)

Answer (score 2):

You may use table inheritance for this, as any table implicitly defines a type. Quoted from [CREATE TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html):

> CREATE TABLE also automatically creates a data type that represents
>   the composite type corresponding to one row of the table. Therefore,
>   tables cannot have the same name as any existing data type in the same
>   schema.

Your example, with tables:

```
create table mytype  (
    f1 int,
    --many other fields...
    fn varchar(10)
);

create table mytype_extended(
  fx int
) inherits (mytype);
```

When describing the table with psql:

```
# \d mytype_extended

       Table "public.mytype_extended"
 Column |         Type          | Modifiers 
--------+-----------------------+-----------
 f1     | integer               | 
 fn     | character varying(10) | 
 fx     | integer               | 
Inherits: mytype
```

Now let's add a column to the base table and check that the inherited table gets it too:

```
alter table mytype add other_column int;
```

```
# \d mytype_extended
          Table "public.mytype_extended"
    Column    |         Type          | Modifiers 
--------------+-----------------------+-----------
 f1           | integer               | 
 fn           | character varying(10) | 
 fx           | integer               | 
 other_column | integer               | 
Inherits: mytype
```